# Samsung SII rom update

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom

I'm a big fan for RR (Resurrection Remix rom) and I'm following it's news and updates since V.1.8.1

But there is something I don't like with rom updating in general, each time updating the rom I need to wipe cache, applications and user details. I hate reinstalling apps. and configure my phone from zero.

Is there a way to relaunch the same settings and apps. after updating the rom.

thanx for your advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-

Things have changed-

As of today, all you need to do is backup the .apk files to your SD card using the backup app of your choice (there are free ones like Astro-) 
And then get an app called "App Installer" --

When you Update the ROM- you can re-install all of your apps with the App Installer--

App Installer hasn't been around too long-- I personally use Titanium-- it has some good features, but it costs money. Worth every cent, IMHO.

ALSO- You *may* not actually need to wipe the data and system before you update the ROM--- so long as you are *upgrading* the ROM and not switching to a different ROM.

(if the chef says wipe, then wipe--)

But a lot of times, you can get away with only wiping davlik+cache